# How to add JSON objects to array state in functional component in react.js

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, setstate

I need to keep all of the information that came from axios in the form of JSON in the state while using the `map` method.

The problem is when I use the `map` method after the axios request, it just adds the last JSON to the state, but I have 9 objects in my JSON

```
const [expensesData , setExpensesData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('API-address')
    .then(res => {
        res.data.map( info => {
            setExpensesData(
                [
                    ...expensesData,
                    {info}
                ]
            )
        })
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
} , [])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [expensesData , setExpensesData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('API-address')
    .then(res => {
        setExpensesData(res.data);
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
} , [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Last line will improve your application performance you application
It will render method called when your expensesData

```
    const [expensesData , setExpensesData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('API-address')
        .then(res => {
            setExpensesData(res.data);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    },[expensesData])
```